# asp.net 3.5 Request variables?

Tags: asp.net, request

I'm looking for a Per Request place to store some variables. I thought there was a name/value dictionary on HttpRequest, but I don't see one (besides Cookies or ServerVariables).  This App is .Net 3.5.

Can anyone suggest a Per Request storage area?

--Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HttpContext.Items` is a per-request store. If you don't already have reference to the context, you can access the current context via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items`.

Comment: Thanks -- I knew it was there, somewhere